# Deleting order in sql request

Tags: sql

The program i m building has to delete a lot of stuff before running.

The line of delete look like

```
Delete * from tablea where po=5;
Delete * from tableb where po=5;
delete * from tablec where n in (select n from tabled where po=5)
delete * from tabled where po=5
```

The problem is that about 10 times in about 500 tables, the link i need to delete is in the child table so i have no more way to delete it s parent

```
Delete * from tablef where po=5;
Delete * from tableg where x in (select x from tablef where po=5)
```

So i m deleting nothing from tableg because there is no info on tablef. Is there a easy way to keep the information without creating a temp table or rewriting the code.

Comment: You can delete child table first and then go for parent table

Comment: It sounds like you want to define cascading delete constraints, to make this easy.

Comment: Alter the parent table definition. Put on delete cascade to column po.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.